# Orderby not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I am sorting on multiple criteria using dynamic sorting, here's my code:

```cs
    public ActionResult WebGrid(int page = 1, int rowsPerPage = 10, string sortCol = "OrderID", string sortDir = "ASC", string sortSecCol = "OrderID", string sortSecDir = "ASC")
    {
        List<Orders> res;

        using (var nwd = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            var _res = nwd.Orders
                .AsQueryable()
                .OrderBy(sortCol + " " + sortDir, sortSecCol + " " + sortSecDir)
                .Skip((page - 1) * rowsPerPage)
                .Take(rowsPerPage)
                .Select(o => new Orders  
                {
```

What I am trying to do in here is I want the column `OrderID` be the secondary sort whenever it is not a primary sort, but it didn't work when I actually selected other column as a primary sort.

In order words, when other column is select as primary sort in descending order, `OrderID` should also be in descending order, I am not sure what did I missed in my code.

The `OrderBy` method I used is come from [here (MSDN)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/UI/WebControls/Dynamic.cs.html).

Comment: Why not use OrderBy().ThenBy()

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Because there is no `ThenBy()` in dynamic sorting...

Comment: Hahaha yes, you're right. My bad. Moving along....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you are using has the following signature:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    string ordering,
    params object[] values
)
```

so the `sortSecCol + " " + sortSecDir` goes to `values` argument, while the whole ordering is supposed to be provided as comma separated list in the `ordering` argument.

You can use something like this instead:

```
var ordering = sortCol + " " + sortDir;
if (sortSecCol != sortCol)
    ordering += ", " + sortSecCol + " " + sortSecDir;
...
   .OrderBy(ordering)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    if (sortCol == "OrderID" && sortDir == "ASC")
    {
        _res = l.OrderBy(x => x.OrderId).ThenBy(x => x.AnotherField);
    }
    if (sortCol == "OrderID" && sortDir == "DESC")
    {
        _res = l.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderId).ThenByDescending(x => x.AnotherField);
    }
    if (sortCol == "AnotherField" && sortDir == "ASC")
    {
        _res = l.OrderBy(x => x.AnotherField).ThenBy(x => x.OrderId);
    }
    if (sortCol == "AnotherField" && sortDir == "DESC")
    {
        _res = l.OrderByDescending(x => x.AnotherField).ThenByDescending(x => x.OrderId);
    }

    _res.Skip((page - 1) * rowsPerPage)
            .Take(rowsPerPage)
            .Select(o => new Orders  
            {
```